# Merging two commands that will appear in columns into one csv file

Tags: powershell

How can I merge the below commands into one .csv file?  I'm brand new to powershell and trying to figure this out.  Basically I want everything to appear in columns from the commands below on the same .csv.

```
$computerinfo = Get-ComputerInfo -Property * | Select-object -Property *
$computerinfo | Export-Csv -Path "$home\Desktop\compinfo.csv"

$ip = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object IPAddress -First 1 
$ip | Export-Csv -Path "$home\Desktop\inventory.csv"
```

Comment: save the two commands to individual $Vars and then use them to build a `[PSCustomObject]` that has the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a calculated property with your [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) or use [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7).

**Calculated Property:**

```
$computerinfo = Get-ComputerInfo
$ip = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -Expand IPAddress -First 1
$computerinfo | Select-Object *,@{n='IPAddress';e={$ip}} |
    Export-Csv -Path "$home\Desktop\output.csv"
```

**Add-Member:**

```
$computerinfo = Get-ComputerInfo
$ip = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -Expand IPAddress -First 1
$computerinfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'IPAddress' -Value $ip
$computerinfo | Export-Csv -Path "$home\Desktop\output.csv"
```